# Solving equation with Complex Numbers and two unknowns.

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following track:

If $z=a+bi$, with the imaginary number $i$, solve the following equation
    $$z^2+|z|^2-18=0$$

Well, first of all I replaced $z$ with $a+bi$ and then $|a+bi|^2$ with $(a^2+b^2)$.

After, I got $a$ as a function of $b$, but in this case I have two unknowns.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Left side will have two parts, the real part and the imaginary part. Set both equal to zero and then you'll have a system of equations in $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After substitution you can solve the first square to obtain:

$$a^2-b^2+2abi+a^2+b^2=18;$$

in other words: $2a^2+2abi=18$. Now $18$ is real, this mean: $a=0$ or $b=0$. If $a=0$ then $0=18$ which is false, so $b=0$; then $2a^2=18$, so the solutions are $a=\pm 3$.

Comment: Correct. Thank you very much! (Grazie 1000)

Comment: You are welcome ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $z$ is a solution, then
$$
z^2 = 18-|z|^2
$$
and hence
$$
|z|^2 = |18 - |z|^2|
$$
Put $t = |z|$. Thus $t^2 = 18-t^2$ or $t^2 = t^2 - 18$, but the second possibility clearly can't occur. Hence $2t^2 = 18$, so $t = \pm 3$, but since $t$ is positive, we must have $t=3$.

Returning to the original equation, it now reads
$$
z^2 - 9 = 0
$$
so $z = \pm 3$.

Comment: Alternatively, from the original equation, $z^2$ must be real, so $z$ is either real or purely imaginary, and you can split into those two cases.

Answer (score 1):

As John Molokach commented, expand the expression to get $$2 a^2+2 i a b-18=0$$ Comparing the real and imaginary parts, you then have $$2a^2-18=0$$ $$2ab=0$$ The first equation gives $a=\pm3$ and the second $b=0$.